# Sending a email on a specfic time interval in windows service

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-services, window

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and Database Sql Server 2010.

I have Created a Window Service which must sent email's when time interval occurs (EMAIL_SENT_TIME)

My Database Contains this columns

```
    Tracker_Id bigint 
,EMAIL_SENT_TIME bigint --this contains interval in which the email must be fired 1800,3600,7200 etc, 
    Last_check datetime --the previous check datetime,
    next_check datetime --the next check datetime
```

Assume table contains this date
tracker_Id | EMAIL_SENT_TIME | Last_check |  next_check 
 100097           1800          datetime       nextdatetime 
 100098           3600          datetime       nextdatetime 
 100099           7200          datetime       nextdatetime 
 100100           1800          datetime       nextdatetime

1800 means 30 mins,
3600 means 1 hours etc.

I want to send email after 30 mins those EMAIL_SENT_TIME are 1800 and so on.

how to solve  this problem....

Comment: WHY down vote tell me so that i will not make mistake's again

Comment: Have you looked at [Quartz.NET?](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net)

Answer (score 0):

Can the EMAIL_SENT_TIME column change for each record or is it a constant? One of the easiest ways to do something on an interval is the System.Threading.Timer class. The first parameter is the callback function (in this case to send an email every time the interval elapses), then state data (this could possibly contain information you want to insert into each email, offset time, and the last is the interval. This class also allows you to change the interval while the Timer is running if your database EMAIL_SENT_TIME value changes.

```
Timer timer = new Timer((x) => SendEmail(), null, 0, EMAIL_SENT_TIME * 1000).
```

In the SendEmail() function you can record the current DateTime.Now in the Last_Check time column. You don't really need Next_Check because you can always add last check plus interval to get that value.

[System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx)

Comment: EMAIL_SENT_TIME is constant. timer interval is defined as 30 mins i.e 1800000 ms

Comment: In that case System.Threading.Timer would be a good solution. Just a heads up though, make sure the Timer object is a member of a class, and not a local object or it can be garbage collected and will not fire. If it is a member of your service class then it will remain active for the duration of your service.

Comment: Your saying that create a Thread timer for each scenario's .i.e thread timer object for 1800  , thread timer object for 3600. i am right or i am missing some thing

Comment: Yes, according to this SO post, you can have thousands of timers at once, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375034/is-system-threading-timer-efficient-enough-for-thousands-of-concurrent-timers. So you could put a List<Timer> as a member of your service, then on your Service OnStart() event, loop through your database entries and spawn off each timer adding it to the list.