# How to add delay without thread.sleep for few seconds using c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using Windows form and dotnet 3.5

I want to add 2 or 3 second delay before delete file

```
//need 2 or 3 second delay here
File.Delete("d:\testing.txt");
```

I need delay just because another operation is performed before deletion and without delay File.Delete gives exception that file is being used by another process

Thanks,

**Edit 1**

I cant whole code is much bigger.
The previous operation before delete file is this

```
System.IO.File.Move(d:\"log.rtf", d:\testing.txt");
```

Comment: Looks like your problem is bigger then. Mind showing the "whole" code?

Comment: What if the file is *still* in use by another process 2 or 3 seconds later?

Comment: You should check if the file is in use by another process, if not Delete it, if it is, re-run the loop, till it has been released, or give a message.

Comment: Whats the problem with using thread.sleep method?

Comment: thread.sleep stop the whole form with other operations so sleep can't help

Comment: You can set a Timer. And you will probably need to be prepared to retry a few times and handle errors.

Comment: I think 2 seconds more than enough.
I am sure deletion file give error (file is beign used by another process) because of file.move

Comment: I am currently using 4 timers already. will it cost performance

Comment: Large numbers of timers need not be a problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375034/is-system-threading-timer-efficient-enough-for-thousands-of-concurrent-timers

Comment: Timers aren't that expensive, and "a lot" starts at 100 or so.

Comment: ok then I will use timer thanks

Comment: @UzairAli I would take a look at my answer, because using sleeps or timers here is a very bad design decision. Thread/inter-processes synchronization is rock-solid and it's the right solution to your problem! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're not in the right track if you want to use a delay here.

This is more a thread synchronization issue.

The most simple approach is the `lock` keyword. If you synchronize some code using `lock`, only one thread will be able to enter in the protected code until other code releases the lock.

For example, if you declare a `private readonly object _sync = new object();` class field and you change your code as follows...

```
lock(_sync) 
{
     File.Delete(@"d:\testing.txt");
}
```

...and also the `File.Move`, which happens before the whole delete, uses a lock against the same `_sync` object...

```
lock(_sync)
{
     System.IO.File.Move(@"d:\log.rtf", @"d:\testing.txt");
}
```

...the whole `File.Delete` will wait until `File.Move` releases the lock (i.e. the `lock` block ends).

In the other hand, if we're talking about multiple processes (different applications or services working with the same file), you'll need a `Mutex`. Mutexes can be named and shared across processes, and it'll work very closer as the code above with `lock` blocks (actually, this is using `Monitor`):

Your code would look like this:

```
// Note mutexes must be instantiated using the same name in both processes!
Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, "FileMutex");

mutex.WaitOne();

try 
{
    File.Delete(@"d:\testing.txt");
}
finally
{
    mutex.ReleaseMutex();
}
```

And...

```
Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, "FileMutex");
mutex.WaitOne();

try 
{
    File.Move(@"d:\log.rtf", @"d:\testing.txt");
}
finally
{
    mutex.ReleaseMutex();
}
```

Also note `.WaitOne(...)` has an overload which accepts giving a timeout.

Learn more about `Mutex` [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f55ddskf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Nice, I never thought that something like this even exist

Comment: @UzairAli No problem, this is why sites like SO are useful!